# List with springboot and thymeleaf

Tags: java, arrays, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to get a list of objects that are sent to the server from the html form as parameters for my list, then I will loop through those entries and then return them through the springboot `th:each`. But it doesn't seem to be working at all. On load the form appears but when I enter a value in it, then it returns an error page and the URL however turns:

```
http://localhost:8080/@%7B/%7D?%24%7Bcontent%7D=hello
```

this output in eclipse says:

```
Expression "content" is not valid: only variable expressions ${...} or selection expressions *{...} are allowed in Spring field bindings
```

Note: content here is the value property in my form.
My controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public HelloList() {
    this.addUs = new ArrayList <>();
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String getlist(@RequestParam (required = false) String content, Model model) {
    if (content != null && !content.trim().isEmpty()) {
        this.addUs.add(content);
    }

    model.addAttribute("list",addUs);
    return "index";
}
```

the index.html looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="amHere: ${addUs}">
            <span th:text="${amHere}">hello! world</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <form action="@{/}" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="content"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This might be a duplicate but it seems like most of the solutions I came across are not helping. So any help is mostly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update: here in stackoverflow "Run code snippet" tab, i can see that after i run the html file, it displays the default child element "hello! world". But on my computer this fails to take place. I see only the form. So i am not sure what is going on.

Comment: you probably want `method="post"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing the initialization of my list in the constructor. I initialized the list by adding a value to it first in the constructor like this.

```
this.addUs.add("Hello World");
```

Because the `@RequestMapping` is mapped to the home path in my case index.html, any request gets sent there automatically. 
[working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpaes.png)

Answer (score 0):

`action = "@{/}"` should be `th:action="@{/}"`.  That's the reason you're seeing the weird url (because it's url encoding `@{/}`).  Thymeleaf only evaluates expressions that start with `th:`.

I'm not sure about the other error.  It looks like the html you've pasted doesn't match up with the error you are getting.

If you urldecode `http://localhost:8080/@%7B/%7D?%24%7Bcontent%7D=hello`, you get `http://localhost:8080/@{/}?${content}=hello`, which doesn't line up with your form.

Comment: Yes you are right i got a typo in the form leaving out the "th"  from from forms action method. I rectified that but still now i cant access the list model even though i can see that any time i pressed to send my value from the from, the url displays the parameter of the and its value.

Comment: "http://localhost:8080/?content=Hello" The error output is `Could not parse as each: "items ${addUs}"`. it seems like when i have th:each="items : ${addUs}" and   th:text="${items}", the list does not appear at all. But when i take them off, the chrome shows the default value "hello! world".